# Javascript Regex patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying figure out if it's possible to aggregate two patterns in a single one.

So my input could be something like this:

```
input = "200px"
input = "200pt"
```

My expected output would be `result = ["200","pt"]` or `["200","px"]`

```
var result = input.match(/[^pt]+|pt/g)
```

Anyone knows if it's possible in a single pattern, handle `pt` or `px` suffixes ?

**Solved**

```
result = input.match(/^([0-9]+)(px|pt)$/).slice(1);
```

or

```
result = input.match(/^([0-9]+)((p[xt]|r?em)).slice(1);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var input = "200px"; // or 200pt;
var result = input.match(/^([0-9]+)(px|pt)$/);
// result: ["200px", "200", "px"]
result = result.slice(1); // ["200", "px"]
```

The RegExp in English:

- `^` start at the beginning of the string.
- `([0-9]+)` match 1 or more digits and capture them.
- `(px|pt)` match `px` or `pt` and capture it.
- `$` end must be at the end of the string.

Comment: Instead of `(px|pt)` *-which works of course-*, you can use `(p[xt])`.

Comment: I don't like to do that. What if you also want to match `em` and `rem` and one of the many other dimensional metrics? Why would you want to be clever with that? I would down vote your comment if I could.

Comment: hi, your suggestion is good, but do you know if there is any other option to consume first match? this is suppose consume any metric but the ideal case was exactly this result = ["value","metric"]

Comment: The first element is always the full match, you can't not have it. You can trim it off by: `result.slice(1)`

Comment: While it's not shorter, it's faster - it does not match `p` twice. Instead of `(px|pt|em|rem)` you'd rather write `(p[xt]|r?em)`

Comment: @Bergi Don't make baseless claims. Prove it (make a benchmark).

Comment: I am not trying to be smart or anything and sorry if I offended you in any manner, I was just pointing out an alternative solution

Comment: @Bergi's comment doesn't deserve a benchmark because you won't notice the difference in this case and you won't need one as the regex engine will first match `p` and won't need to save any states for backtracking then it will look for an `t` or `x` with no need for saving any states again.

Comment: If you think it's faster you're welcome to prove it. Just because you can reason your way into it doesn't mean it's actually true. My regexp is more readable so it's faster. See how that makes no sense whatsoever? More often than not, trying to be clever will end up costing you more time. I always prioritize readability, then performance then fanciness. Putting fanciness first gives you fancy bugs.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: As Sniffer explained, it doesn't need backtracking. Of course, a clever regex engine *can* optimise this, and the difference is [hardly noticeable](http://jsperf.com/repeating-regex-parts). And I agree, that readability here wins over regex design rules.

Comment: I don't disagree with the logic, I disagree with the statement that it doesn't deserve a benchmark. I die a little inside when I see a clever solution get more votes than a good readable solution. Novice programmers typically don't recognize the benefit of readable code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use capturing groups:

```
input.match(/(\d+)(p[tx])/)
// -> Array ["200px", "200", "px"]
```

To get the exact `result` you wanted (without matching the whole string), you can `split` before the `p`:

```
input.split(/(?=p)/)
// -> Array ["200", "px"]
```

Comment: +1 for the split technique which looks like the most efficient answer.